# Aggregate initialization pre-C++17

Tags: c++, c++14, aggregate-initialization

Consider the following class hierarchy, made from aggregates:

```
struct Foo {
    int k;
    double d;
};

struct Bar : Foo {
    int i;
};
```

Now, let's say I would like to initialize an object of type Bar from an object of type Foo, giving extra argument for `i`. (For reason to dull to discuss here, adding a constructor to `Bar` which accept `Foo` and `int`, or modifying definition of `Bar` or `Foo` in any other way is out of question). In C++17 I would use aggregate initialization:

```
auto make(const Foo& f) {
    return Bar{f, 42};
}
```

This is not available in C++14. Is there anything else I can do mimic desired behavior in C++14? I am trying to avoid something like

```
auto make(const Foo& f) {
    Bar b;
    b.k = f.k;
    b.d = f.d;
    b.i = 42;
    return b; // or return Bar{f.k, f.d, 42};
}
```

Where the thing I am trying to avoid is making `make` aware of internals of `Foo` - i.e. `make` is fine to know how to initialize extra members of `Bar`, but would prefer not to initialize members of `Bar` which are common with `Foo`.

Comment: If there was a way to mimic it without making it a non-aggregate, why would they have added it to the standard in C++17?

Comment: @NicolBolas well, some of the features are enabling, while others are simply reducing the syntax overhead (for example, fold expressions could be implemented in C++14 with just a bit more typing, but same semantic). I am looking for a possible way of doing the same thing, potentially with more typing, but same semantic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
auto make(const Foo& f) {
  Bar b;
  static_cast<Foo&>(b) = f;
  b.i = 42;
  return b;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Shame on me for not seeing that.